# Count the number of elements for a nested array in Atlas Mongo pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, atlas

I have the following document structure

```
_id:2
lines:Array
```

I want to retrieve the number of `lines` items for each document

```
{
  _id: "$_id",
  numberLines: {
    $size: "$lines"
  }
}
```

It doesn't work !

[image]

Then I want get the total `lines` items for the entire documents using Aggregation Pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group only allows [accumulators operations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#std-label-accumulators-group), and `$size` is not one of those.

However it seems you just need to use the `$project` or `$addFields` stage as you're not really `$group`ing anything.

like so:

```
{
  $project: {
     _id: 1,
     numberLines: { $size: "$lines" }
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to get the total number, I added a new stage `count: { $count: '$numberLines'}` but it returns nothing

Comment: `$count` is basically a specific `$group`, can you explain why are you trying to `$group`? Regardless you can see [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1FxQP6DBbFW) example - this uses what i suggested using, `$project` or `$addFields`.

Comment: In fact, I want to get out the total number of lines for all documents in the db

Comment: I added $group stage and it gives th desired result. Thanks @Tom
`[{$project: {
  _id: "$_id",
  numberLines: {
    $size: "$lines"
  }
}}, {$group: {
  _id: null,
  total: {
    $sum: "$numberLines"
  }
}}]`

Comment: Gotcha, you can simplify it like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ouu7D6sMyPH)